# JXTA P2P application over internet

Tags: p2p, jxta

I am learning JXTA and want to master it. I downloaded the tutorial programs from jxta website
I have run all those programs from only one PC and worked perfectly fine.
But I want it to work over internet. 
My friend also has an internet connection. We tried to run socket client on his machine while socket server program was running on my machine. I also tried to make myjxta (a jxta p2p application) to work over internet but had no success. 
We both have ADSL connection and has D-Link ADSL router GLB-802C.
While setting up the router I did entered username and password. There not any proxy configuration for browser.
So is it required to do the proxy configuration for JXTA if yes how should I do it..

The ipconfig for ethernet is as follows

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8139/810x Family Fast Ethernet NIC
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-14-78-06-2A-A8
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5584:3f17:f0c5:d774%11(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, September 03, 2009 7:50:51 AM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 03, 2009 7:50:51 AM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234886264
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-11-FB-93-03-00-14-78-06-2A-A8
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 208.67.222.222
                                    208.67.220.220
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I am trying to do it since week, I need help to understand this....
I want some guidelines how should I proceed with this because there is not much information available for JXTA on internet. Thank you for any help ..

I am changing a question a little bit I want to run MyJXTA (a readymade JXTA application downloaded from JXTA website) to work over internet. I did provided configuration screenshot links in the comment, as well as screenshot of MyJXTA application when I run it. thanks for any help...

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

> I just figured out that there is some
>   problem with tcp server socket and my
>   isp. I did confirmed it with python
>   SOCK_STREAM here is the thread -
>   [Python SOCK_STREAM over internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448193/python-sockstream-over-internet) .
>   Only Datagram works on my pc . I do
>   not know whether jxta used tcp server
>   socket or not. Can there be any other
>   problem ?

Screenshot of [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) -
http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/3816/59237360.jpg

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: I just downloaded MyJXTA latest version and it has all the rendezvous and relay settings made. But still I cant communicate over internet, My settings are 
http://img182.imageshack.us/img182/4454/84911496.png
http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/7820/44632248.png
But still I cant find any peers or groups when I search for it...

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/9866/95906703.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a networking perspective, you've got two machines, each of which is behind a firewall.

Unless their is some 'broker' service that is publicly accessible to both of you, you're not going to be able to connect to each other without poking some holes in your firewalls. 
I'll bet the simple example code you downloaded doesn't provide for that 'broker'.

From the docs I found on the java site, it sounds like the thing your missing is a 'Public Rendezvous peer'.

The [java site](https://jxta.dev.java.net/) has lots of stuff on [jxta](https://jxta.dev.java.net/), a forum and an IRC channel.

If you want to debug this at the network level, [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can help.

Comment: Screenshot of wireshark - http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/3816/59237360.jpg . I just figured out that there is some problem with tcp server socket and my isp. I did confirmed it with python SOCK_STREAM here is the thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448193/python-sockstream-over-internet. Only Datagram works on my pc . I do not know whether jxta used tcp server socket or not. Can there be any other problem ?

Comment: From your screen shot it looks like all the communication is tcp.

It may be helpful for you to have a capture of a functional conversation with a local p.c. 

What your looking for is some difference in the communication pattern. Example: My local setup sends a ping here, but the remote doesn't.

This is a pretty low level way to go about solving this problem. I can't believe there isn't more logging functionality built into this library to debug communication problems.

Comment: I have asked in jxta forum where log files present, hope i get the answer, thanks for helping ...

Answer (score 1):

you need to bring up a rendezvous server outside of both your NATS.

Those links describes some of the options you can use:

1. http://osdir.com/ml/java.jxta.devel/2007-04/msg00011.html
2. http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jxtaian_2/index2.html?page=3

if I remember correctly from my JXTA days, you can also use a public rendezvous server.

Comment: Hi, I did used rendezvous server for MyJXTA a jxta p2p application. Its configuration is http://img182.imageshack.us/img182/4454/84911496.png and http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/7820/44632248.png But I cant see any peers or groups... When I access urls for rendezvous and relays  from browser I can see seeds...But it does'nt work in configuration ... I have other p2p programs in python which work perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

Hi (from the leader of the two latest release of JXTA for Java), you need to set-up a RDV peer with a public IP address. Then, this peer must be set as a seed in your two EDGE peers. Then, socket communication should work (it does in our tests). Cheers.