# How can a peer find another peer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jxta

There is an important issue that is not clear when someone search information about how the peers find each other in JXTA. Let´s assume that we have got two peers one in Berlin and the another one in London, which is a rendezvous. My question is how can the peer in Berlin find the peer in London?

1. What methods in JXTA to solve this ?
2. Can you post an example?

Comment: If there are only those two peers, and they have no knowledge about each other, they will just not find each other.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Is there any way that I can make them to know each other?

Answer (score 1):

Googling jxta Peer Discovery Protocol we find http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/networking/Wilson/wilson_ch04.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the URI of a public Rendezvous peer which is a pre-existing Peer visible to both your peer in London and Berlin. When you start your peers, you seed the NetworkConfigurator with this rendezvous peer's URI, something like this:

```
NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager(...)
NetworkConfigurator config = manager.getConfigurator();
config.addRdvSeedingURI("tcp://123.123.123.123:1234");
```

I think @JVerstry says something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953034/1240660